# Firebase Android addChildEventListener explanation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need some clear explanation with `addChildEventListener` and Query event binding.

I use firebase in my android app. In the `onCreate()` method of my activity, I create something like this...

```
fiDbQuery = fiDbRef.child("users").orderByChild("name");
fiDbQuery.addChildEventListener(// listener //);
```

... where `fiDbQuery` is a `Query` instance in the activity (global var) and `fiDbRef` is a `DatabaseReference` instance in the activity too, where I already set the initial value.

all is well, when activity first loaded, all the users data are loaded and shown. But then, I have some button to sort this data according to users field, either by email, age, name, etc.

and in those buttons `onClick`event listener, I do something like this... (this one is the sort by age button)

```
fiDbQuery = fiDbRef.child("users").orderByChild("age");
```

... and I didn't provide the `addChildEventListener` function because it is already "added" on `onCreate()` method, right? The data aren't loaded, but if I add the `addChildEventListener` function it works again.

My question is, is it save to use multiple `addChildEventListener` into one Query, or is there any performance issues with that? All I want to accomplice is reusing the `fiDbQuery` instance without the need to add `addChildEventListener` every single time I modify the `fiDbQuery`.

Thank You for your help.

**EDIT**:

all those query I make use the exact same listener. Only one listener for all those query which populate a `listView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add the `addChildEventListener` again. What you need to do, is to change the logic of your actions a little bit.

First define all your queries like this:

```
nameQuery = fiDbRef.child("users").orderByChild("name");
ageQuery = fiDbRef.child("users").orderByChild("age");
//and so on
```

To solve your problem, you only need to use an `if else-if statement` which sounds like this:

```
Query query;
if(nameButton.isClicked()) {
    query = nameQuery;
} else if(ageButton.isClicked()) {
    query = ageQuery;
}

query.addChildEventListener( // listener. //);
```

This means that according on which button the click was made, you are using the desired query. With this code, you just use the `addChildEventListener` once.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there everything ok, can i help you with details?

Comment: I am sorry I can only check SO today, and thank you for your response. But isn't this if else if statement must be called whenever a button is pressed? and if so, isn't it the same with calling addChildEventListener whenever a button pressed, hence multiple adding? @Alex

Comment: No, the condition of pressing the button is in the `if-else-if` statement it self.. I have created that `if-else-if` statement to call either `query = nameQuery` or either `query = ageQuery`. In this way, is  you are calling `addChildEventListener ()` method only once.

Comment: ah really sorry again I just checked this post. Yes it solved my issue, I mark it as answer and upvoted it. Thanks Alex.